# AndroidBootstrap button height

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-bootstrap-widgets

How to make [AndroidBootsrap](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) buttons height smaller?

The padding between the button top/bottom and the text is too important compared to standard buttons. Using the `bootstrapbutton:bb_size="small"` button property also reduces the text and still keeps an important top/bottom padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Self-answered question, as it may help other users)

Edit AndroidBootstrap project > src > com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap > BootstrapButton.java:

Replace

```
    layout.setPadding(0, paddingB, 0, paddingB);
```

By

```
    layout.setPadding(0, (int)(paddingB*0.7), 0, (int)(paddingB*0.7));
```